# Recursively Edit CSV to Subdirectories using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a series of subdirectory folders that each have a "_Invoice.csv".

```
/Invoice List/
              Invoice1folder/
                             ..._Invoice.csv
              Invoice2folder/ 
                             ..._Invoice.csv
              Invoice5folder/
                             ..._Invoice.csv
              Invoice9folder/
                             _Invoice.csv
```

With each "_Invoice.csv", I have columns [A,B,C,D]. I am trying to recursively search through all subdirectory folders, open each "_Invoice.csv" file and reduce the columns to only [A,C] and then save it as "_Invoice_Reduced.csv".

```
"_Invoice.csv"       "_Invoice_Reduced.csv"
 A B C D        =>              A C
 1 2 3 4        =>              1 3
```

My current attempt is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

columns_to_keep = ['A','C']
final_form= pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('*_Invoice.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df = df.loc[;columns_to_keep]
        df = df.to_csv(f'{file.name}_Invoice_Reduced.csv')
   if file.endswith('*_Invoice_Reduced.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        final_form= final_form.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

TLDR: I am attempting to create a script that goes into every subdirectory, reduces a pre-existing CSV, reduce the columns of CSV down and save the subset. Then after it has read through all subdirectories, combine the reduced files into a single big_frame.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the behaviour of your current code, and how is it short of what you want it to do?  First thoughts are you probably don't want `*` in the `endswith` test (unless you use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)), and that the first time you run the code your second if statement (looking for `_Invoice_Reduced.csv`) wont trigger, because the filenames looped over are generated before you do any processing.

Comment: You could have caught at least some of these with a little basic debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job.

Instead of opening, removing columns, saving and moving on; I have opted for opening only with the reduced columns, saving this reduced DataFrame, then appending to `df`. This will result in all the reduced files being stacked in this one DataFrame.

Using `path = "."` goes from the current directory

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame()
columns_to_keep = ['A','C']
path = "."
pattern = "*_Invoice.csv"

for file in Path(path).rglob(pattern):
    output_file = "{}/{}{}".format(file.parent, file.stem, "_Reduced.csv")
    _df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=columns_to_keep)
    _df.to_csv(output_file, sep=",", index=False, header=True)
    df = pd.concat([df, _df])
```