# Read folder of many csvs into dictionaries each with their name being the file name

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, jupyter

I have a folder of csv files. Each csv file was a dictionary. I want to read each of these csvs back into dictionary with the filename as the dictionary name.

For example. My folder 'CSV-Dictionaries' has many csv files
'file1.csv' 'file2.csv' etc. I want to read these separate files so that their dictionary names are file1 and file2.

This is how I created the csvs. But now I want to read them using a for loop.

```
#dictionaries o f data
file1 = {'item11':1, 'item12': 2}
file2 = {'item21':3, 'item22': 4}

#dictionary of the data dictionaries with names
dicts = {'file1' : file1, 'file2' : file2}

#use pandas to make a dataframe and the write data frame to csv
for a_dict in dicts:
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts[a_dict], orient="index", columns=['value']).to_csv("~/Downloads/"+a_dict+".csv", index_label="key")
```

Comment: Somthing like `{fname: open(fname) for fname in os.listdir('CSVFolder') if fname.endswith('.csv')` would construct the dict

Comment: Put the file dictionaries into the main dictionary directly.  No need to create intermediate names.

Comment: I don't get it when you say that there are dictionary on csvs, what you mean?

Comment: Also is not clear if you want the file object or the file contents at dict keys, I would suggest file objects, and deferring the file reads to as late as possible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively Edit CSV to Subdirectories using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013225/recursively-edit-csv-to-subdirectories-using-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all the files in a folder using `os.listdir(path_to_dir)` and then iterate every file in that directory, opening it and saving the name as the key like you describe. The code might look something like;

```
import os

import pandas as pd

def read_in_files_and_save_to_dict(folder_path):

    csv_dict = {}

    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        filename_path = f`{folder_path}/{filename}`
        csv_dict[filename] = pd.read_csv(filename_path).to_dict()
```